# How to override tax details in Vendor Bill via SOAP in NetSuite ERP?

Tags: netsuite, netsuite-rest-api

SuiteTax installed and enabled.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/preface_1496364245.html#SuiteTax

I try to import vendor bill via SOAP web service. Vendor bill has tax details overridden. I always have an error:

> [USER_ERROR] Please enter value(s) for: Tax Details Reference, Tax
> Type, Tax Code, Tax Basis, Tax Rate, Tax Amount (ERROR)

I can import vendor bill via SOAP web service with 1 line of items, for instance. It works well. I can use tax details overriding via NetSuite UI:

- check tax details override checkbox.
- set  Tax Details Reference, Tax Type, Tax Code, Tax Basis, Tax Rate, Tax Amount
- NetSuite accept this. Everything is OK.

However, when I try to use SOAP web service to import vendor bill with tax details overridden, I always get an error:

> [USER_ERROR] Please enter value(s) for: Tax Details Reference, Tax
> Type, Tax Code, Tax Basis, Tax Rate, Tax Amount (ERROR)

All fields were filled in. Tax Details Reference was set the same in item and in tax details line. I tried SOAP update procedure to add overridden tax details to well formed vendor bill - the same error.

How to send vendor bill with tax details overridden to NetSuite via SOAP webservice.

Answer (score 0):

I have found what went wrong. I forgot about special fields that work in pair with usual plain type field (string, int, double ...). It's:

fieldName**Specified**

These fields must be set to TRUE.

Here is an example of source code for SuiteTalk C# SOAP web service:

```
vendorBill.taxDetailsList = new TaxDetailsList();
vendorBill.taxDetailsOverride = true;
vendorBill.taxDetailsOverrideSpecified = true;
vendorBill.taxDetailsList.replaceAll = true;
vendorBill.taxDetailsList.taxDetails = new[]
{
   new TaxDetails()
   {
      taxDetailsReference = taxDetailsRef,
      taxRate = 10,
      taxRateSpecified = true,

      taxAmount = 1,
      taxAmountSpecified = true,
      taxCode = new RecordRef()
      {
         internalId = "528",

      },
      taxType = new RecordRef()
      {
         internalId = "35",
      },

      taxBasis = 5,
      taxBasisSpecified = true
   }
};
```